# throw exception in async

Tags: exception, f#

I have the following code:

```
member public this.GetData(uri: string) = async {
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask(httpClient.GetAsync uri)
    return res
}
```

When the property `res.IsSuccessStatusCode` is `false` I would like to throw an exception, how can I achieve this. The following code won't compile:

```
member public this.GetData(uri: string) = async {
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask(httpClient.GetAsync uri)
    match res.IsSuccessStatusCode with
    | true -> return res
    | false -> raise new Exception("")
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You certainly need to wrap `new Exception(...)` in brackets, but that is not sufficient in this case - both branches of the match statement need to return a value, so you also need to insert `return`:

```
async {
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask(httpClient.GetAsync uri)
    match res.IsSuccessStatusCode with
    | true -> return res
    | false -> return raise (new Exception(""))
}
```

This is actually easier to write using an `if` computation which can contain body that returns unit (and throws an exception if the operation did not succeed) - and so you do not need `return` in that case:

```
async {
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask(httpClient.GetAsync uri)
    if not res.IsSuccessStatusCode then
        raise (new Exception(""))
    return res 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that compiles. Something else doesn't work, but that is another problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

So the first part is that you need to wrap the `new Exception()` with brackets to make sure that F# interprets the code correctly.

```
raise (new Exception(""))
```

or you can use either of the pipe operators

```
raise <| new Exception("")
new Exception |> raise
```

or you can change the type and use `failwith`

```
failwith "some message"
```

Secondly, you need to return from both branches, so prefix `raise` with `return`

Comment: Thanks again :) The solution of @tomas-petricek works better :)